# Problem when use pop() to remove more than one items

Tags: python

test code:

```
function=['6005', '6110', '6016', '6104', '6151', '6008', '6112', '6062', '6018', [], '6024', [], '6018', '6012', '6027', '6147', '6028', '6027', '6155', '6004']
empty=[]
for i in range(len(function)):
    if function[i]==' ':
        empty.append(i)
    elif function[i]==[]:
        empty.append(i)
print(empty)
for i in range(len(empty)):
    function.pop(empty[i])
print(function)
```

as we see, function[9] and function[11] are empty
I successfully found the address `[9, 11]`(that is what 1st print does)

but I failed to remove these two elements in the list

I got

```
['6005', '6110', '6016', '6104', '6151', '6008', '6112', '6062', '6018', '6024', [], '6012', '6027', '6147', '6028', '6027', '6155', '6004']
```

as result, it just pop function[9], but function[11] still exist

Why does it happen and how to remove both function[9] and function[11]?

PS: I have to do it in this way, not simply delete every '[]' I found. This is just a part of the program, I need to use these address to delete the 10th and 12th element in another list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pop the 9-th element, your previously 11-th element becomes the 10-th element. So, at the next iteration, you are deleting the wrong element. A simple fix would be to delete from the end. Eg

```
for i in reversed(empty):
    function.pop(i)
```

Note: in python, you don't have to iterate in C-style (eg. `a[i]` for all `i` values). You can directly write `for value in values`.

Answer (score 1):

Once you pop the index will be changed you need to run again and use pop to the second empty list of function.

```
function = [x for x in function if x]
```

Or:

```
list(filter(None, function))
```

Or:

```
function.pop(9)
function.pop(10) # instead of 11 because index changed.
```

Or use this twice:

```
function.remove([])
```

Naming a list as function is very bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You should not alter a list you are iterating on, it could produce non consistent results.

A simple and reliable way to get what you want is to use [the filter function](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#filter), [a lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/functional.html?highlight=lambda#small-functions-and-the-lambda-expression) and the fact that an empty list is `False` in a boolean context:

```
function = ['6005', '6110', '6016', '6104', '6151', '6008', '6112', '6062',
            '6018', [], '6024', [], '6018', '6012', '6027', '6147', '6028',
            '6027', '6155', '6004']

print filter(lambda item: bool(item), function)
# ['6005', '6110', '6016', '6104', '6151', '6008', '6112', '6062', '6018', '6024', '6012', '6027', '6147', '6028', '6027', '6155', '6004']
```

As pointed out by @Filiphappy, this version only filter empty list while your code also filters "single space strings". For an iso functionality example, you can use this version:

```
print filter(lambda item: item not in (' ', []), function)
```

Comment: This is incorrect, original code also removes space-strings **' '**. So, to do the same thing as the original code, use this: **a = list(filter(lambda item: item != ' ' and item != [], function))**

Comment: @FilipHappy I dit not see any empty string in the input data. If you want to be so robust you will also need to take care of empty dicts, empty sets, empty tuples, False values and None values.

Comment: No, I just think it should do the same thing as the original code, so owner doesn't use that and get errors later on. If it doesn't the same thing, you could say it only removes empty items. Anyway, that is just a detail, but may save some nerves for the owner.

Comment: @FilipHappy ok. it seems I read you first comment too quickly and misunderstood what your were meaning. Thanks for pointing out this, I will update :)

Answer (score 1):

You can build a list of booleans saying whether or not an element is empty like this:

```
def is_not_empty(x):
    if isinstance(x,str):
        x = x.strip()
    return bool(x)

not_empty = [is_not_empty(x) for x in function]
```

You can then filter the list using itertools.compress:

```
from itertools import compress
function_not_empty = list(compress(function,not_empty))
```

You will also be able to use this to filter the same elements from other lists.

*NB - I have edited this answer in response to Filip Happy's comment about missing strings with a single space in them*

Answer (score 1):

when you delete the 9th element in the list, the 11th element shifts to 10th. This will be more complex when you have more empty elements. I recommend to delete it by checking for empty element using

`function = [x for x in function if x]`

The code above check for non-empty element and gives back the list you want.

If you are concerned to remove via index, I would recommend to remove from decreasing order of the position. i.e., as you knew [9, 11] elements are to be removed, remove the element with highest index first. `function.pop(11)` then `function.pop(9)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [enumerate](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/), i.e.:

```
empty_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(function) if x == [] ]
# [9, 11]
```

---

[Demo](https://ideone.com/yYW6Yi)

---

## Old Answer:

You can use [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_filter.asp) to remove empty strings from a list.

```
new_list = filter(None, old_list)

# ['6005', '6110', '6016', '6104', '6151', '6008', '6112', '6062', '6018', '6024', '6018', '6012', '6027', '6147', '6028', '6027', '6155', '6004']
```

---

For python 3 use:

```
new_list = list(filter(None, old_list))
```

---

## Note:

Avoid using **function** as a variable name as it can be confusing and it's generally considered a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete the first empty list, the index of everything after this item is reduced by one (this list is 1 item shorter now). So you are deleting a second item but insted of the second empty list you delete the '6018'.

You could make two loops, first one to find the indexes, second one to delete the empty lists:

```
for i in range(len(function)):
    if function[i]==' ':
        empty.append(i)
    elif function[i]==[]:
        empty.append(i)

i=0  
while(i<len(function)):
    if function[i]==[]:
        del function[i]
        i=i-1
    elif function[i]==' ':
        del function[i]
        i=i-1
    i=i+1
```